# Calculation of a complex limit

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I was trying to calculate the following complex limit :

$$\lim_{z \to 1}\frac{z^2+i}{z^4-1}$$

My solution book stands that the answer must be $-\frac{1}{2}$. However, my intuition says that can not be true.

I believe that the solution must be $\infty$ and I was trying to prove it using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, but it looks a bit difficult.

Comment: The book must have a typo. $z=1$ is a non-removable discontinuity and the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I suspect it is $\lim\limits_{\large{z\to i}}\dfrac{z^2+1}{z^4-1}$, which gives the desired limit.